# "noframenumbering" doesn't work in beamer

Tags: beamer

"noframenumbering" doesn't work.
Specifically, using the following code, the current page number is shown as "2/3".
But I would like to show like "1/2", excluding the title page and specified another page.
Do you have any solution for treating this problem?

```
¥documentclass[dvipdfmx,11pt,notheorems]{beamer}

¥usetheme{Madrid}
¥usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
¥setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][left]
¥setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
¥setbeamercovered{transparent}

% Footer
¥setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
¥setbeamerfont{footline}{size=¥normalsize, series=¥bfseries}
¥setbeamercolor{footline}{fg = black, bg = black}
¥setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{fg = black}

¥usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
¥usepackage{amsthm}
¥usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
¥usepackage{textcomp}%
¥usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
¥usepackage{otf}%
¥usepackage{helvet}%

¥begin{document}

¥begin{frame}[noframenumbering, plain]
¥titlepage %
¥end{frame}

¥begin{frame}¥frametitle{Agenda}
¥tableofcontents %
¥end{frame}

¥section{Title}
¥begin{frame}¥frametitle{aaa}
¥end{frame}

¥end{document}
```

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in a single post

Comment: Sorry I'll separate questions.

Answer (score 3):

The `noframenumbering` option works fine - but you are not showing frame numbers 
but page numbers.

If you want to show frame numbers instead, you can use `\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]`

```
\documentclass[11pt,notheorems]{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][left]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

% Footer
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamerfont{footline}{size=\normalsize, series=\bfseries}
\setbeamercolor{footline}{fg = black, bg = black}
\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{fg = black}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
%\usepackage{otf}%
\usepackage{helvet}%

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[noframenumbering, plain]
\titlepage %
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Agenda}
\tableofcontents %
\end{frame}

\section{Title}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{aaa}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```